# Tomcat 7 not starting. Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler

Tags: tomcat7

When I am trying to run the Tomcat 7 using startup.bat with java 1.6.0_05 then it is working. In case i am changing the version to jdk1.6.0_45 or jdk1.7.0_65 the it is giving error. This seems something is wrong with java version but i could not figure out what could be the possible reason.

```
C:\Programs\apache-tomcat-7.0.54-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-7.0.54\bin>java -version
java version "1.6.0_05"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.6.0_05-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 10.0-b19, mixed mode)
This is working  fine.




But in case I change the jdk to jdk1.6.0_45 or jdk1.7.0_65. 
C:\Users\mbanerjee>java -version
java version "1.7.0_65"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_65-b19)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.65-b04, mixed mode)

Tomcat 7 is no more starting. It is giving exception.


Jul 15, 2014 11:21:09 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: Loaded APR based Apache Tomcat Native library 1.1.30 using APR version 1.4.8.
Jul 15, 2014 11:21:09 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: APR capabilities: IPv6 [true], sendfile [true], accept filters [false], random [true].
Jul 15, 2014 11:21:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener initializeSSL
INFO: OpenSSL successfully initialized (OpenSSL 1.0.1g 7 Apr 2014)
Jul 15, 2014 11:21:10 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-7733"]
Jul 15, 2014 11:21:10 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
SEVERE: Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-7733"]
org.apache.tomcat.jni.Error: 730106: The requested service provider could not be loaded or initialized.  
    at org.apache.tomcat.jni.Socket.create(Native Method)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint.bind(AprEndpoint.java:420)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:640)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:434)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:978)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:559)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:813)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:638)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:663)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:280)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:454)

Jul 15, 2014 11:21:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService initInternal
SEVERE: Failed to initialize connector [Connector[HTTP/1.1-7733]]
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[HTTP/1.1-7733]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:559)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:813)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:638)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:663)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:280)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:454)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:980)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: org.apache.tomcat.jni.Error: 730106: The requested service provider could not be loaded or initialized.  
    at org.apache.tomcat.jni.Socket.create(Native Method)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint.bind(AprEndpoint.java:420)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:640)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:434)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:978)
    ... 13 more

Jul 15, 2014 11:21:10 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
Jul 15, 2014 11:21:10 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
SEVERE: Failed to initialize end point associated with ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
org.apache.tomcat.jni.Error: 730106: The requested service provider could not be loaded or initialized.  
    at org.apache.tomcat.jni.Socket.create(Native Method)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint.bind(AprEndpoint.java:420)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:640)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:434)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:978)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:559)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:813)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:638)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:663)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:280)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:454)

Jul 15, 2014 11:21:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService initInternal
SEVERE: Failed to initialize connector [Connector[AJP/1.3-8009]]
org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to initialize component [Connector[AJP/1.3-8009]]
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:106)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService.initInternal(StandardService.java:559)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.initInternal(StandardServer.java:813)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:638)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.load(Catalina.java:663)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.load(Bootstrap.java:280)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:454)
Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Protocol handler initialization failed
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:980)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.init(LifecycleBase.java:102)
    ... 12 more
Caused by: org.apache.tomcat.jni.Error: 730106: The requested service provider could not be loaded or initialized.  
    at org.apache.tomcat.jni.Socket.create(Native Method)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AprEndpoint.bind(AprEndpoint.java:420)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.AbstractEndpoint.init(AbstractEndpoint.java:640)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol.init(AbstractProtocol.java:434)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.Connector.initInternal(Connector.java:978)
    ... 13 more

Jul 15, 2014 11:21:10 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 2310 ms
Jul 15, 2014 11:21:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Jul 15, 2014 11:21:10 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.54
Jul 15, 2014 11:21:10 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Programs\apache-tomcat-7.0.54-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-7.0.54\webapps\docs
Jul 15, 2014 11:21:12 PM org.apache.catalina.util.SessionIdGenerator createSecureRandom
INFO: Creation of SecureRandom instance for session ID generation using [SHA1PRNG] took [739] milliseconds.
Jul 15, 2014 11:21:12 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory C:\Programs\apache-tomcat-7.0.54-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-7.0.54\webapps\docs has finished in 1,618 ms
Jul 15, 2014 11:21:12 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Programs\apache-tomcat-7.0.54-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-7.0.54\webapps\examples
Jul 15, 2014 11:21:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory C:\Programs\apache-tomcat-7.0.54-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-7.0.54\webapps\examples has finished in 977 ms
Jul 15, 2014 11:21:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Programs\apache-tomcat-7.0.54-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-7.0.54\webapps\host-manager
Jul 15, 2014 11:21:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory C:\Programs\apache-tomcat-7.0.54-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-7.0.54\webapps\host-manager has finished in 112 ms
Jul 15, 2014 11:21:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Programs\apache-tomcat-7.0.54-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-7.0.54\webapps\manager
Jul 15, 2014 11:21:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory C:\Programs\apache-tomcat-7.0.54-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-7.0.54\webapps\manager has finished in 114 ms
Jul 15, 2014 11:21:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory C:\Programs\apache-tomcat-7.0.54-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-7.0.54\webapps\ROOT
Jul 15, 2014 11:21:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deployment of web application directory C:\Programs\apache-tomcat-7.0.54-windows-x64\apache-tomcat-7.0.54\webapps\ROOT has finished in 90 ms
Jul 15, 2014 11:21:13 PM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina start
INFO: Server startup in 3007 ms
Jul 15, 2014 11:21:13 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer await
SEVERE: StandardServer.await: create[localhost:8005]: 
java.net.SocketException: Unrecognized Windows Sockets error: 10106: create
    at java.net.ServerSocket.createImpl(ServerSocket.java:308)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.getImpl(ServerSocket.java:257)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.bind(ServerSocket.java:376)
    at java.net.ServerSocket.<init>(ServerSocket.java:237)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardServer.await(StandardServer.java:426)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.await(Catalina.java:777)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina.start(Catalina.java:723)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:321)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:455)

Jul 15, 2014 11:21:13 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-7733"]
Jul 15, 2014 11:21:13 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol pause
INFO: Pausing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
Jul 15, 2014 11:21:13 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService stopInternal
INFO: Stopping service Catalina
Jul 15, 2014 11:21:13 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-7733"]
Jul 15, 2014 11:21:13 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["http-apr-7733"]
Jul 15, 2014 11:21:13 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol stop
INFO: Stopping ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
Jul 15, 2014 11:21:13 PM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol destroy
INFO: Destroying ProtocolHandler ["ajp-apr-8009"]
What can be the probable reason for this issue? I looked at many forums but did not get any solution for it .

Any help will be really appreciated.
```

Comment: Two things: show the relevant portions of your `server.xml` and report if you have installed the [Tomcat Native connector](https://tomcat.apache.org/native-doc/) for your operating system.

Answer (score 1):

Well, the obvious thing is that you can't initialize the APR.  That's all this gives you.

As with all java things, you will just have to "troubleshoot" until it works.

Chances are you didn't install APR (usually called tomcat-native or something), or that the APR library you've installed has binary compatibility troubles with the rest of your system, or it's installed but somehow become corrupt; notice how it's failing on a call to a native method.

The MSDN description of the socket error you're getting might be handy:

> The requested service provider could not be loaded or initialized. This error is returned if either a service provider's DLL could not be loaded (LoadLibrary failed) or the provider's WSPStartup or NSPStartup function failed.

If you don't know how to make APR for windows, [the documentation is a good start](https://apr.apache.org/compiling_win32.html).